# moving train of cars simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation

We are trying to simulate moving cars using Matlab Here's the code we wrote:

```
function []=moving_cars()
    figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
    x = linspace(0,30,10);
    y2=0.6;
    y3=0.2;
    y4=-0.2;
    axis([0,20,-0.4,1.5])
    ax = gca;
    hold on
    //%road
    plot(x,y2*ones(size(x)), 'LineWidth', 1,'Color','black')
    hold on
    plot(x,y3*ones(size(x)),'--', 'LineWidth', 1,'Color','black')
    hold on
    plot(x,y4*ones(size(x)), 'LineWidth', 1,'Color','black')
    hold off
    axis off
    title('( Moving cars Simulation )')
    set(gcf,'color','w')
    //%load image data
    [imageData0, map, alpha] = imread('00.png', 'png');
    [imageData1, map, alpha] = imread('20.jpg', 'jpg');
    [imageData2, map, alpha] = imread('27.jpg', 'jpg');
    //%create Figure and Axes objects
    f1 = figure(1);
    a0 = axes('Parent', f1);
    a1 = axes('Parent', f1);
    a2 = axes('Parent', f1);
    //%Add Image objects to axes
    image(imageData0, 'Parent', a0);
    image(imageData1, 'Parent', a1);
    image(imageData2, 'Parent', a2);
    //%Resize and move the Image objects
    set(a0, 'Units', 'Pixel', 'Position', [-160 150 150 70],'Box','off','Visible','off');
    set(a1, 'Units', 'Pixel', 'Position', [-160 150 150 70],'Box','off','Visible','off');
    set(a2, 'Units', 'Pixel', 'Position', [-160 150 150 70],'Box','off','Visible','off');
    axis off
    //%generate the train
    Train= car_train()
    //%moving the cars
    check_type(Train,a0,a1,a2);
end
function [Cars]= car_train()
    //%create random car train (10 cars between 1:2)
    Cars = round((2-1).*rand(5,1) + 1);
end
function[]= check_type(Cars,a0,a1,a2,a3,a6)
    for k = 1:length(Cars)
        if(Cars(k)==1)
            for i=1:2:1800
                set(a1, 'Position', get(a0,'Position') + [i 0 0 0]);
                drawnow
            end
        elseif(Cars(k)==2)
            for i=1:2:1800
                set(a2, 'Position', get(a0,'Position') + [i 0 0 0]);
                drawnow
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that we need a train of cars to be moving not car by car (after the car moves 200 the next car type in the Car array moves and so on till the end of the Car array)

Can any one help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to swap these `for` loops:

```
for k = 1:length(Cars)
    if(Cars(k)==1)
    for i=1:2:1800
        ...
```

Because right now you are going for each car, do every move. You need to do, for each position move ever train car.

```
function[]= check_type(Cars,a0,a1,a2,a3,a6)
   for i=1:2:1800
       for k = 1:length(Cars)
           if(Cars(k)==1)
               set(a1, 'Position', get(a0,'Position') + [i 0 0 0]);
               drawnow
           elseif(Cars(k)==2)
                set(a2, 'Position', get(a0,'Position') + [i 0 0 0]);
                drawnow
          end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: @user3332603 Sure, there you go. This is untested. You will need to do the testing leg work for yourself.

Comment: @ Ben what about the if statement that moves the car according to the car type??

Comment: @user3332603 What do you mean? The `if` statement i removed is just to separate the car 1 and car 2 to end. Did you try this?

Comment: @user3332603 sorry i see what you mean now, fixed.

Comment: yes I tried your code, the first car only moves across the screen. We have two types of cars (1&2) the if statement was to check the car type generated randomly by the function "car_train "and stored in the array "Cars" so it can't be removed

Comment: with the new code only car 2 is moving across the screen no matter    the number in the array Cars is (it should be after the first car move "i=200" the next car in the array appear and so on)

Comment: I guess the problem is in a0 position or the i value